# Which data model should i use

Tags: mongodb, relational-database, data-layer, database

I want to develop web application which will be keeping results of game of teams within last 100 years and add actual results. My problem is that i don't know which data relation model should i choose relational or NoSQL. I have many years of experience with relational databases.

Data sample:
TEAM A : Team B

Result 2:0.

I want to keep this event as win for Team A and loose for Team B.

I want to query such information:

1. Wins and  looses for team A
2. Wins and  looses for team B
3. Team A meet Team B  n times in history with Y wins and Z looses.

I suppose to have  less then 1.Mi of  play records.

Which important pros and cons should i consider by choosing the data layer? 
Which data model is better for performance to calculate these facts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Relational. You have very little data. Keep it simple.

Comment: I am afraid that i have m:n relation cross table.

Comment: If you have less than a million rows, you have a small database. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a database of this size, it really doesn't matter.

Really you should consider how the data will be accessed and your familiarity with relational or MongoDB.

Personally I consider myself better with Mongo so i would use that - but the only reason would be personal opinion.

**To answer:** The best solution is the one you are most comfortable developing - with DB of this size there is no performance issues with either. assuming you stick to best practices.